# R - grep() matches, but str_remove_all() fails with non-ascii characters

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I am parsing a table from a PDF and attempting to clean my readings. I'm trying to do a simple `str_remove_all()` of some common failures in my OCR. I've created a regular expression that matches my strings, however, when I put the regular expression into `str_remove_all()` it fails. See the code below:

```
> regexpattern <- '^(\\s*[[:punct:]]*\\s*)+|^\\s*\\d{1,2}\\s*$|^\\s+$|(^\\s* 
[[:ascii:]]{1}\\s*$)|(^\\s*[^[:ascii:]]{1}\\s*$)'

>   strg <- "Ú"

>  grep(regexpattern,strg, perl = T)
[1] 1

>  str_remove_all(strg,regexpattern)
[1] "Ú"
```

Any ideas as to why my `str_remove_all()` is failing? Thanks!

Comment: str_remove_all() require two arguments, [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_remove) `str_remove_all(string, pattern)`. str_replace_all() also fails either way

`str_replace_all(strg,regexpattern, "")
[1] "Ú"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT: Removed prior answer that while technically worked wasn't the issue.

The problem is that your regex isn't doing what I think you intend it to do. The first alternative in your regex is `\\s*[[:punct]]*\\s*`. None of those elements need to be present, which means that *everything* will match and none of your other alternatives will be checked. So when `stringr::str_remove_all` uses that regex it will run through the alternatives on that first character, use the first alternative since it matches, and ignore the character moving on. Change it to `\\s*[[:punct]]+\\s*` and you'll have better success.

```
> regexpattern <- '^(\\s*[[:punct:]]*\\s*)+'
> grep(regexpattern,strg, perl = T, value=TRUE)
[1] "Ú"
> regexpattern <- '^(\\s*[[:punct:]]+\\s*)+'
> grep(regexpattern,strg, perl = T, value=TRUE)
character(0)
> regexpattern <- '^(\\s*[[:punct:]]+\\s*)+|^\\s*\\d{1,2}\\s*$|^\\s+$|(^\\s*[[:ascii:]]{1}\\s*$)|(^\\s*[^[[:ascii:]]]{1}\\s*$)'
> str_remove_all(strg, regexpattern)
[1] ""
```

Comment: @MakoEyedSoldier - updated the answer to give you what you need

Comment: yup... that'd be why. Stare at the same piece of code for hours, and your mind turns into a potato. Totally missed my greedy indicator. Thanks so much for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp does not remove all non-ASCII characters.

```
grep('^(\\s*[[:punct:]]*\\s*)+|^\\s*\\d{1,2}\\s*$|^\\s+$|(^\\s* 
     [[:ascii:]]{1}\\s*$)|(^\\s*[^[:ascii:]]{1}\\s*$)',
     c("Úa", "Ú", "b"), perl = TRUE, value=TRUE)
[1] "Úa" "Ú"  "b"
```

Try `"[^u0000-u007F]+"`:

```
grep("[^u0000-u007F]+", c("Úa", "Ú", "b"), perl = TRUE, value=TRUE)
[1] "Úa" "Ú"
```

Then also `str_remove_all()` works as expected:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(c("Úa", "Ú", "b"), "[^u0000-u007F]+")
[1] "a" ""  "b"
```

Comment: Nope, not me downvoting :) Thanks for the help, you've helped me narrow down a bit, but while `regexpattern <- ^\\s*[^u0000-u007F]{1}\\s*$` works, `regexpattern <- "^(\\s*[[:punct:]]*\\s*)+|^\\s*\\d{1,2}\\s*$|^\\s+$|(^\\s*[[:ascii:]]{1}\\s*$)|^\\s*[^u0000-u007F]{1}\\s*$"` does not. I've already just split my replace into two steps, but i'd really like to just have one regular expression check